# Are Visual Studio 2010 projects load fine in VS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

A couple of questions:

1. I have Visual Studio 2010 projects.  If I install VS 2012, will this load fine, even though they are built for .Net 4.0?
2. Can I convert a 4.0 project to 3.5 (compile it) in VS 2012?

Regards
Tea

Comment: For the second question, you can convert it by just setting the framework version of the project to 3.5 but since .NET 3.5 is not a superset of .NET 4.0; you may have compile errors for the methods/libraries that doesn't exist in 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is "YES".

I can open all of my VS2010 solutions/projects on VS2012 without any issue. Did you get any error?

Comment: I haven't installed it yet, hence the questions.  If I have framework 3.5 installed does VS 2012 allow compliation to that version?

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek: As I have already answered "YES". You can compile code from .NET 3.5 as well. And the best part is you can keep both the versions of Visual Studio as well if you decide to do so. Like, I have just started using VS2012 and so I have both the versions at this moment in one of my machines.